# What encryption is used when data is in transit from Azure to Snowflake?

Tags: azure, encryption, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

My source data is in Azure blobs. I am loading this in Snowflake table via ADF pipeline. I know that snowflake uses E2E encryption for its data and also that we can use master key when giving COPY COMMAND in snowflake.
I have understood that key vault can be used in Azure for source and sink.

However, it is not much clear to me. How exactly does encryption work for files moving from azure to snowflake table. Is client-side encryption (master key) possible ?
Are there any other ways to do this ?

Comment: Encryption to protect from whom? Naturally data is encrypted in transit by mechanisms like https and ssl, but is that enough to answer your question?

Comment: You could look here for your answers: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html

Answer (score 0):

When the data is stored in cloud storage service, the user may optionally encrypt the data files using **client-side encryption.**

[Client-side encryption](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html#client-side-encryption) provides a secure system for managing data in cloud storage. Client-side encryption means that a user encrypts stored data before loading it into Snowflake. The cloud storage service only stores the encrypted version of the data and never includes data in the clear.

To load client-side encrypted data from a customer-provided stage, you create a named stage object with an additional MASTER_KEY parameter using [CREATE STAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#create-stage), and then load data from the stage into your Snowflake tables. The MASTER_KEY parameter requires a 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) key encoded in Base64.

> The master key is the Base64-encoded
> string of the customer’s secret master key. As with all other
> credentials, this master key is transmitted over Transport Layer
> Security (HTTPS) to Snowflake and is stored encrypted in metadata
> storage. Only the customer and the query-processing components of
> Snowflake are exposed to the master key and are therefore able to
> decrypt data stored in the stage.

Please visit [Data Encryption in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html) to get in-depth details.

You can also check https://www.snowflake.com/blog/data-encryption-with-customer-managed-keys-for-azure/